# Is it possible to execute multiple commands on one line in TortoiseHg's console?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

[TortoiseHg's Output Console](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/workbench.html#output-log-console) only allows a limited subset of commands from the guest system. Because of this, a lot of syntax seems to not be supported in it, such as using `&` to chain commands together. Is it possible to find another way to do this inside of their console? I'm using TortoiseHg 3.7.1 on Windows 7.

For context: I'm looking to create macros of a sort to execute multiple `hg` commands with one button. Tortoise has a custom tool area which allows users to execute their own commands, linked up to a toolbar button. There's a few different merge patterns that require constantly updating and merging branches, so I decided to create one of these tool commands. Unfortunately, as it requires running multiple commands,  it errors out after ignoring `&`, citing invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only hack-ish workaround I've found so far is that tortoise exposes the ability to execute `cmd` on Windows machines, but locks up if you stay inside it.

However, it's possible to use a command like: `cmd /k "[commands] & exit"` which immediately boots the user back into the tortoise console again.

You can use this to solve the problem by telling cmd to execute your multiple commands, separated by the usual `&`, then killing the application with `exit`.

TortoiseHg tools also provides variables, such as the path to the root of the repository directory, to be able to set up the environment correctly in your temporary `cmd` session.